# Regex to match string containing two ETH address in any order

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to have array from message that contain ETH address from text.

**Example text:**

> You have incoming invoice for 0xc7d688cb053c19ad5ee4f48c348958880537835f from 0xc7d688cb053c19ad5ee4f888848958dd0537835f with time spent 18 : 32 and remark test 1

**Expected output:**

```
[
 '0xc7d688cb053c19ad5ee4f48c348958880537835f,
 '0xc7d688cb053c19ad5ee4f48c348958880537835f'
]
```

Comment: Is there a space after the ETH address?

Comment: Does the address have a fixed length, or how can the first one run together with the word "from"?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @SumitJha Yes it has space

Comment: @ArndtJonasson, yes 40 alpha numeric after 0x

Comment: `\b0x[a-f0-9]{40}\b`

Comment: @guijob it shows match but i need all match in array

Comment: so you can use `match`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `match` with following regex `(\b0x[a-f0-9]{40}\b)`:

```js
let str = 'You have incoming invoice for 0xc7d688cb053c19ad5ee4f48c348958880537835f from 0xc7d688cb053c19ad5ee4f888848958dd0537835f with time spent 18 : 32 and remark test 1'

let resp = str.match(/(\b0x[a-f0-9]{40}\b)/g)

console.log(resp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [regular expression](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)`/(0x[a-f0-9]{40})/g;`. Here is a fast solution.

```js
const regex = /(0x[a-f0-9]{40})/g;
const str = `You have incoming invoice for 0xc7d688cb053c19ad5ee4f48c348958880537835ffrom 0xc7d688cb053c19ad5ee4f888848958dd0537835f with time spent 18 : 32 and remark test 1`;
let m;
let result1 = [];
//Solution 1
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    result1.push(m[0]);
}
console.log(result1);
//Solution 2
let result2 = str.match(regex);
console.log(result2);
```